# Normalize infinite range into finite one

Tags: trigonometry, infinity

First of all; I'm a programmer, not a mathematician so please excuse the informality of my math-vocabulary.

I have a series of slopes, calculated out of random angles (their tangents). These angles will always be located in the I and IV quadrants i.e. there are no angles "pointing to the left".

As you probably know, the tangent curve goes from -infinity to +infinity in this range.

I need to normalize the slopes into a range from -1 to 1. This means that the slope of an angle approaching (pi/2) should get closer and closer to 1 instead of infinity.

I would like to know how to do this in two ways:

1) Preserving a smaller tangent curve in my new range

2) Making it a linear range

Comment: It isn't clear to me what exactly you want to do. Why not just normalize the angles to be from -1 to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could first normalize your point so that it is at distance $1$ from the origin, then take the resulting $y$-coördinate.

In other words, given $(x,y)$, you would be calculating $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, which is the sine of the angle from the $x$-axis.

Comment: To put it another way, if you are not given the point $(x,y)$ but only the tangent $t$, you can calculate $\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Normalisation as such implies linearity.  If you want to include tan(90) you will simply see values of unity at +/-90 and zero elsewhere.
You can perform a non-linear function on tan (generally called companding rather than normalisation), but unless the non-linear function relates in some way to the desired solution you may just as well use the original angle [same as atan(tan(theta))].